# Python logger not outputing anything despite loglevel is set

Tags: python, logging

I know this question has been asked many times before but I've never seen that after setting the level it doesn't outputting anything. Any suggestions what I do wrong? The following example does not output anything.

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("Test")
```

Comment: Where are you trying to output it to?  You haven't assigned any handlers in the code shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a handler:

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())  # <<< Add a handler
logger.debug("Test")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Under what circumstances does it automatically assume that it's StreamHandler?

Comment: There are many handlers, some outputs to console, others to files:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html

Comment: I don't know which circumstances that the logging module use the StreamHandler automatically. I looked up the doc, but not finding any answer.